# Which article we can use with word 'Rain'

Tags: articles

I am learning English. I have one confusion about articles. I have gone through one usage of articles in English. What I can use with word 'Rain'
Should it be 'a' or 'The'.

Comment: ***The rain** in Spain falls mainly on the plain. **A rain** of spears fell upon the advancing army. **Rain** is a favourite topic of conversation in England.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Rain" is often used with *no* article:

- Rain is falling.
- We expect rain this evening.
- We expect it to rain this evening.
- We expect rain to start this evening.

If you've mentioned a particular rainfall event, you might refer back to it with "the rain":

- There was terrible storm last night. The rain went on for hours.
- The rain kept us from taking our walk.

"A rain" is much less common. You might see phrases like "a *gentle* rain" or "a *hard* rain", but you'll rarely see the phrase "a rain".

Comment: Thanks for explanation. It clears confusion.

Comment: You're very welcome. I know what articles sound right in English, but I often can't explain _why_ they're right or wrong. English must be a terrible struggle if your native language doesn't use articles as often. (English is a terrible struggle, period!)

Comment: "A rain" is used but sometimes sounds rural: "A rain is coming on." You might also hear "before" or "after a rain," treating the rain as an event: "[Why does it smell good after a rain?](https://wxguys.ssec.wisc.edu/2012/04/30/why-does-it-smell-good-after-a-rain/)"

Answer (score 0):

Like most uncountable nouns, *rain* can be used with or without *the*, according to the general rules about *the* (which are complicated, I know).

Again like many uncountable nouns, it *can* be used countably (and so take *a*) when the reference is to different kinds of rain: eg "a persistent rain", "a gentle rain".

Unusually, *rain* can also be plural, but generally only in the sense of "the seasonal rainfall" of somewhere that distinguishes a dry and a rainy season. eg. "That year the rains came late".